# Filter and sort numeric values represented as text in Cassandra tables

Tags: database, cassandra

Suppose I have a text column in a Cassandra table. This Column has numeric values represented textually, e.g.

```
|...|...|myTextColumn|...|...|
|...|...|   '1000'   |...|...|
|...|...|    '200'   |...|...|
|...|...|    '35'    |...|...|
```

If I use indexes I am able to query by myTextColumn and ask for all values that are smaller than let's say 300:

```
select * from myTable where myTextColumn<'300' ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

And by doing so I have a three-fold problem:

1. the row such that myTextColumn='1000' is listed in the results
2. the row such that myTextColumn='35' is not listed in the results
3. sorted results will show '1000' before '200' and '200' before '35'

Note that I understand why this happens, the why is **not** my question. My question is whether it is possible to address this and if so how, without recurring to the following approaches: **i)** change the column type **ii)** add leading zeros so that all values have the same number of digits.

Thank you for your time. Best regards.

Comment: This is not possible in cassandra, If you don't change the data type

Comment: Why you declare this as `text` type ??

Comment: If you are sure that this is not possible than I'll accept it as the correct answer. Can you prove/demonstrate or at least explain it somehow?

Comment: Before that can you tell me, why you are using `text` data type. What is the use case ?

Comment: Does it matter? In reality this column can yield also non-numeric values. Recently a client asked for this feature i.e. amongst those that are numeric, sort them in ascending/descending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to solve this problem using only queries. However I ended up solving it by adding an extra digit to the numeric values inserted in myTextColumn.

All numeric variables are prefixed with their own amount of digits, e.g. one thousand is 41000, two hundred is 3200. Of course, forty-one thousand is 541000 and thirty-two thousand is 43200.

To ensure that the prefix is always a single digit even for large numbers than we can use Base16 (or 24 or 32 if we want to support larger numbers), e.g. A1234567890.

This ensures that the results are always correctly filtered **and sorted**.

To follow-up the original example, the table becomes:

```
|...|...|myTextColumn|...|...|
|...|...|   '41000'  |...|...|
|...|...|    '3200'  |...|...|
|...|...|    '235'  |...|...|
```

hence if I perform the query:

```
select * from myTable where myTextColumn<'3300' ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

I will get {235,3200}, which contains the correct result in the correct order.